# Dynamically change font size in gvim?

Tags: vim, gvim

I'd like to be able to dynamically change the font size in `gvim`.

Essentially, the common zoom-in/zoom-out functionality you find in a lot of software.

So if I press `Ctrl+=`, the font size gets bigger.  If I press `Ctrl+-`, the font size decreases.  And, ideally, if I press `Ctrl-0` the font size returns to my default size.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure it is, via [zoom.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2321)

(it is mapped to + and - by default, but I gather you know how to change that to your liking).

Comment: That script specified in the zoom.vim does not work. I get following error on trying it in VI. Error detected while processing function <SNR>9_ZoomIn:
line 2:
E18: Unexpected characters before '='

Comment: It looks like nowadays this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Looking at the source code for `zoom.vim` (v0.5) and `:help 'guifont'` makes it obvious that the plugin only works on platforms separating the name and size with a ':' character, which is only true for some environments. An alternative is [fontsize.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2809) which takes proper care to be multi-platform aware.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my AntiX 4.9 using keyboard (not numpad) keys.
It is the zoom feature of Vim 8.1 and it provides me more view of text in vertical split screen mode.

`[Ctrl][-]         decrease font size`
`[Ctrl][Shift][+]  increase font size`
`[Ctrl][0]         restore font size`

Some additional info, because I am using a Debianized, small version of vim.
You can compare to your version: vi --version | less
Maybe try building your own version with what you need and drop it in /usr/local/bin, which will override the default version in the /usr/bin location.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun 15 2019 16:41:15)
Included patches: 1-875, 878, 884, 948, 1046, 1365-1368, 1382, 1401
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -extra_search      -mouse_sgr         -tcl
-arabic            -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -termguicolors
+autocmd           -file_in_path      -mouse_urxvt       -terminal
-autochdir         -find_in_path      -mouse_xterm       +terminfo
-autoservername    -float             +multi_byte        -termresponse
-balloon_eval      -folding           -multi_lang        -textobjects
-balloon_eval_term -footer            -mzscheme          -textprop
-browse            +fork()            -netbeans_intg     -timers
+builtin_terms     -gettext           -num64             -title
-byte_offset       -hangul_input      -packages          -toolbar
-channel           +iconv             -path_extra        -user_commands
-cindent           -insert_expand     -perl              -vartabs
-clientserver      -job               -persistent_undo   +vertsplit
-clipboard         +jumplist          -printer           +virtualedit
-cmdline_compl     -keymap            -profile           +visual
+cmdline_hist      -lambda            -python            +visualextra
-cmdline_info      -langmap           -python3           -viminfo
-comments          -libcall           -quickfix          +vreplace
-conceal           -linebreak         -reltime           +wildignore
-cryptv            -lispindent        -rightleft         -wildmenu
-cscope            +listcmds          -ruby              +windows
+cursorbind        -localmap          +scrollbind        +writebackup
-cursorshape       -lua               -signs             -X11
-dialog            -menu              -smartindent       +xfontset
-diff              -mksession         -startuptime       -xim
-digraphs          -modify_fname      -statusline        -xpm
-dnd               -mouse             -sun_workshop      -xsmp
-ebcdic            -mouse_dec         -syntax            -xterm_clipboard
-emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +tag_binary        -xterm_save
-eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -tag_old_static    
+ex_extra          -mouse_netterm     -tag_any_white
```

Comment: I have a very hard time understanding this answer. Does it state that by default the mentioned key bindings should be causing the change of font size described in Vim 8.1 on Debian? That is with no configuration required either by adding plugins or specifying anything at all in `.vimrc`? or what is the claim? Would it be possible to rephrase the answer to make it more clear, please?

Comment: This is not what the question author is asking. As shown in your answer your vim version is without GUI, so the key bindings are recognized by the **terminal** and changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I made a plugin that does exactly this and you can also use the mousewheel when holding down Ctrl.

Works on Linux and Windows. I plan to add Mac support at some point.

[image: resizing gvim]

https://github.com/eggbean/resize-font.gvim